# How to add variable in between strings in ansible -playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Im using ansible 2.9.2, i have a playbook that copys a file to a virtual machine in a vcenter,
i need to put a var in a string :

```
   somevar = home
   dest: 'c:\Users\"{{ somevar }}"\Desktop\test'
```

This way didnt work, the error i get :

```
msg = 'A specified parameter was not correct
```

I want to get it like this :

```
  dest: 'c:\Users\home\Desktop\test'
```

How can i do it ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
vars:
  somevar: home
tasks:
  - name: some task
    dest: "c:\Users\{{ somevar }}\Desktop\test"
```

Always use double quotes for variable interpolation for the whole line

Comment: `dest: "c:\Users\{{ somevar }}\Desktop\test"
                      ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they`

Comment: @BatchenRegev I assume you have defined the variable under vars in your playbook. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Use double backslash. `dest: "c:\\Users\\{{ somevar }}\\Desktop\\test"`